# Same App listed twice in Device aministrators list of Settings

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, device-admin, android-settings

Developed device admin application which just after installed & go to settings --> Security --> Device administrators same app is listed twice. This happens only in Nexus 6 Android 5.0 device.

Manifest declaration

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.app.android.lock.DeviceLockReciever"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" />
 </receiver>
```

P.S: when enabled device admin by the app, only one is checked in settings --> Security --> Device administrators. Other duplicated entry is never used.